# How can I make my Array to return a randomly value?

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I make my Array to return a randomly value?
I want AirUnit to return a value between 1 and 3.
I want LandUnit to return a value between 4 and 6.
I want WaterUnit to return a value between 7 and 9.

Comment: public function getRandom():Unit
  {
   var unitList:Array = ["AirUnit", "LandUnit", "WaterUnit"];
   for (var i:int = 0; i < unitList.length; i++) 
   {
    // Display the elements in the Output panel.
    trace("Element " + i + ": " + unitList[i]);
   }

Comment: y don't you use three different arrays?

Comment: Ok, but how do I do my Array then?

Comment: What's your question? You have an array of Strings, and you want to return Numbers?? Weird

Comment: `var my_ary:Array = ["a","b","c"];

var random_no:Number = Math.round(Math.random()*2);
trace(random_no+"-----"+my_ary[random_no]);`

Comment: @ Pranav Hosangadi  : He used `Unit` not `uint`.

Comment: @ Benny Geo - Can you show me how to do a Array with AirUnit & LandUnit and WaterUnit, and returning a value?

Comment: U wanna return a number or string?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRandom():uint
{ 
    var unitList:Array = ["AirUnit", "LandUnit", "WaterUnit"]; 
    for (var i:int = 0; i < unitList.length; i++) 
    { 
        // Display the elements in the Output panel. 
        var random_no:Number = Math.round(Math.random()*2);
        //trace("Element " + unitList.indexOf(unitList[random_no])+ ": " + unitList[random_no]); 
    }
    return random_no;
}
trace(getRandom());
```

If you wanna get random values only use the below one.

```
function getRandom():uint
{ 
    return Math.round(Math.random()*2);
}
trace(getRandom());
```

Comment: Oooooooo I got one big problem solving my game ...                1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type int to an unrelated type units:Unit.                                                            I think my problem is something doing with my classes ....

Comment: Its ur own class? then, How do I know its actions?

Comment: I dont understand your questions?